# Why does Grafana return different values for a counter metric on different ranges

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

My Grafana dashboard returns different values for a counter metric with different ranges. I think it's not supposed to.

The metric is `sum(notification_publisher_mail_total) - sum(notification_publisher_mail_errors)`. It should be a constant in different ranges since it is the sum of two counters.

Here are my examples:

[image: With today range]

[image: With this week range]